# How to use Ruby's xmpp library behind a HTTP proxy

Tags: ruby, proxy, xmpp, google-talk

I want to use to the xmpp4r gem to send notifications to gtalk from my Rails app. However I am behind a HTTP proxy and hence cannot use regular jabber. Also, xmpp4r supports HTTPBind but it seems gtalk does not. So is there a way to use HTTPBind with gtalk?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your xmpp4r operations inside the block offered by Net::HTTP::Proxy?

Answer (score 1):

Use proxifier http://rubygems.org/gems/proxifier.

If your proxy is configured on the environment already (ex. by setting the environment variable http_proxy) you can simply add the following two lines to your code.

```
require "proxifier"
require "proxifier/env"
```

This enhances the used TCPSocket to support connection via proxy.

[xmpp4r](/questions/tagged/xmpp4r)[proxifier](/questions/tagged/proxifier)